# How to convert an integer column in the model to be used as a string in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

For database columns that are integers that "represent" strings, what is the best way to show the string value in the view?

For example, if I collect "payment_method" values as integers in my form as follows:

```
<%= f.select :payment_method, { "Visa" => "1", "Mastercard" => "2", "Amex" => "3"} %>
```

How can I show the saved integer as a string in my view files? What can I add to my model, so that

```
<%= @relevantvariable.payment_method %>
```

or something similar returns string values like "Visa", "Mastercard" or "Amex" instead of their respective integer values?

Thanks much for handling such a basic question!

Comment: Couldnt understand the need to showing a integer value as string in view file. Did you mean that your database column is storing only corresponding `id(i.e, 1)` of a `PaymentMethod(i.e, Visa)` and you want to show the `Name (Visa)` of the payment system instead of the `id(1)`?

Comment: Exactly. I am currently only saving the id, but would like to see the name in the view. I figured this was the simplest way to save a small list of options in my database. (As opposed to: 1) allowing the user to enter a string, which may lead to misspellings and homonyms, or 2) referencing a second database that contains the names.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either don't use an integer value, and store the payment method directly as a string in the db, or create a PaymentMethod model.

With the association set up, you'd be able to refer to the name of the payment method as so:

```
<%= @relevantvariable.payment_method.name %>
```

Don't try to manually handle lists of names / ids - that will quickly get unmanageable.

Edit: after reading your comment, if you went with the first option and stored a string in the table, definitely don't allow the user to type the value directly, maintain a list on the model (or similar), that you seed your dropdown from, that way you're still constraining the possible values. You could even add a custom validator if you want to be certain what you putting in the database.

Comment: Thanks @cheeseweasel. I'm hesitant with the 1st option because users can come up with endlessly inventive ways of misspelling payment methods. The 2nd options was my default, but it seems like an extra layer of processing for a simple short list of options that I don't expect to change. Is there no way to offer a list of names without making a second model? I say this because [the Agile Development with Rails book] (http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) has an example of a form like that in my example. The book doesn't cover how to show the integer as a string.

Comment: Well, there are always other ways of doing this. Personally I use the second option because you're managing your data in one place - I don't like putting data in code. However, the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405047/create-a-flexible-localized-ruby-on-rails-list-of-values has quite a nice solution.

Comment: @cheeseweasel: Great finding. was looking for something similar :)

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely the way to go if you need to localise, but otherwise I feel it's hiding the data somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

I'd stick with cheeseweasel solution but you can do one thing to show that on your view...

```
<% if @relevantvariable.payment_method == 1 %>
<%= "Visa" %>
<% else %>
<%= "Mastercard" %>
```

You probably would want to use a switch/case instead but you got the idea

As I said I think you should stick with cheeseweasel solution since there are many problems with this approach... it's your call

Answer (score 1):

So you have your payment methods in a separate table `payment_methods` and the owner ( say user) contains a `has_one` relationship with it

```
class User < AR::Base
   has_one :payment_method
end
```

Then show the payment method name just like

```
<%=
    @user.payment_method.name #or whatever you have. 
%>
```

However, while you are loading the `@user` data, you can perform a `eager loading` by `:include`.  Like

```
User.find(user_id, :include => :payment_method)
```

This will load the `PaymentMethod` data earlier even for multiple users with single query.

Comment: Thanks @Samiron Paul. This is helpful if I have a separate payment_methods table. However, wouldn't it be even more efficient if I didn't have a second table? Or is that not best practice? I say this because [the Agile Development with Rails book] (http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) has an example of a form like that in my example. The book doesn't cover how to show the integer as a string.

Comment: well i feel that, somehow you have to store the supported payment methods in a single place which will be more manageable. Usually its done by Database. Otherwise if `payment_method` is just a column in your `user` table, you need to get the unique set of available values each time you want to show the options. That would be bad unless you cache them at the beginning. However, this approach is not manageable.

Comment: if the book really showing this example `<%= f.select :payment_method, { "Visa" => "1", "Mastercard" => "2", "Amex" => "3"} %>` then they probably storing numbers only.